# Including validation set in my code for a Linear SVM classifier returns a Type error

Tags: machine-learning, python, svm

I'm using a predict function for a linear SVM classifier:

```
def predict(self, train_file: str, test_file: str, lower_case: bool) -> pd.DataFrame:
"Train model using sklearn pipeline"
train_df = self.read_data(train_file, lower_case)
dev_df = self.read_data(dev_file, lower_case)
learner = self.pipeline.fit(train_df['text'], train_df['truth'])
# Fit the learner to the test data
test_df = self.read_data(test_file, lower_case)
# assuming dev_df is validset
dev_df['pred'] = learner.predict(dev_df['text'])
test_df['pred'] = learner.predict(test_df['text'])
return test_df, dev_df
```

And the predict function refers also to:

```
    def run_classifier(files: Tuple[str, str, str],
               method: str,
               method_class: Base,
               model_file: str,
               lower_case: bool) -> None:
"Inherit classes from classifiers.py and apply the predict/accuracy methods"
train, dev, test = files  # Unpack train, dev and test filenames
result = method_class.predict(train, test, lower_case)
method_class.accuracy(result)
# Plot confusion matrix
make_dirs("Plots")
print(result)
fig, ax = plot_confusion_matrix(result['truth'], result['pred'], normalize=True)
ax.set_title("Normalized Confusion Matrix: {}".format(method.title()))
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig("Plots/{}.png".format(method))
```

Where the dev set is not really taken into consideration. When I run predict, I receive this error: `predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lower_case` but I don't understand how to solve it.

Comment: is method_class the name of your class ? If so, no self is needed in the function declaration and that would explain why he thinks lower_case is missing. Otherwise try method_class.predict(train=train, test=test, lower_case=lower_case) and pls reupload the error

Comment: hi, method_class helps me because I have many classifiers and specifying it when running the code changes the outcome. What should I do?

Comment: I am not sure I quite understood but this seems fine. Have you tried declaring your function as `def predict(train_file: str, test_file: str, lower_case: bool)` instead of `def predict(self, train_file: str, test_file: str, lower_case: bool)`? And have you tried calling predict with `method_class.predict(train=train, test=test, lower_case=lower_case)`?

Comment: As for the second one, it says it got an unexpected argument (train) or I don't understand what you meant at all... I am basing on this repo (https://github.com/prrao87/fine-grained-sentiment)

Comment: Yes sorry that's a typo, I meant `method_class.predict(train_file=train, test_file=test, lower_case=lower_case)`

Comment: based on the repo you link, method_class is meant to be a Class therefore method_class.predict is meant to be a class method not an instance method, Class method are declared without specifying a self (as they are not linked to an instance but a class) using `def predict(train_file: str, test_file: str, lower_case: bool)` should fix your problem

Comment: it still gives me the error: predict() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: that's good news, that confirms the idea that you are supposed to declare your function without the self argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113035/discussion-between-mprouveur-and-anna).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the repo you linked in the comment section (github.com/prrao87/fine-grained-sentiment), method_class is meant to be a Class not an instance. Therefore method_class.predict is meant to be a static method not an instance method, Static method are declared without specifying a self (as they are not linked to an instance but a class) declaring your function as `def predict(train_file: str, test_file: str, lower_case: bool) should fix your problem`.

Some reference on the topic : https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/python-instance-static-class-methods/